# Gson for Android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to use Gson to parse this JSON:

```
{
    "status": "status",
    "lang": "lang",
    "guid": "guid",
    "name": "name",
    "tags": "tags",
    "address": "address",
    "description": "description",
    "size": "M",
    "url": "http:\/\/",
    "email": "mymail@mysite.com",
    "fax": "",
    "tel": "000 000 00 00",
    "total_votes": "0",
    "total_value": "0",
    "rate": 5,
    "open2424": "0",
    "category_main_name": "category_main_name",
    "category_name": "category_name",
    "category_main_name2": "category_main_name2",
    "category_name2": "category_name2",
    "category_main_name3": "category_main_name3",
    "category_name3": "category_name3",
    "park_type": "park_type",
    "park_handicap": "0",
    "park_free": "1",
    "park_description": "",
    "datemodinfo": "2012-12-15 18:18:05",
    "sponsor": "2",
    "sponsorstart": "2012-12-16 13:38:51",
    "sponsorend": "2013-12-16 13:38:51",
    "zip": "zip",
    "town": "town",
    "area": "area",
    "latitude": "latitude",
    "longitude": "longitude",
    "distance_info": {
        "distance": 10,
        "unit": "unit"
    },
    "image": "image",
    "url": "url",
    "open": "1",
    "openinghours": [{
        "schedules": {
            "day0": {
                "periods": [{
                    "from": "09:00",
                    "to": "12:30"
                },
                {
                    "from": "14:00",
                    "to": "18:00"
                }],
                "date": "2013-08-12"
            },
            "day1": {
                "periods": [{
                    "from": "09:00",
                    "to": "12:30"
                },
                {
                    "from": "14:00",
                    "to": "18:00"
                }],
                "date": "2013-08-13"
            },
            "day2": {
                "periods": [{
                    "from": "09:00",
                    "to": "12:30"
                },
                {
                    "from": "14:00",
                    "to": "18:00"
                }],
                "date": "2013-08-14"
            },
            "day3": {
                "periods": [{
                    "from": "09:00",
                    "to": "12:30"
                },
                {
                    "from": "14:00",
                    "to": "18:00"
                }],
                "date": "2013-08-15"
            },
            "day4": {
                "periods": [{
                    "from": "09:00",
                    "to": "12:30"
                },
                {
                    "from": "14:00",
                    "to": "18:00"
                }],
                "date": "2013-08-16"
            },
            "day5": {
                "date": "2013-08-17"
            },
            "day6": {
                "date": "2013-08-18"
            }
        },
        "title": "title"
    }]
}
```

I parse the JSON with this code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
response = gson.fromJson(reader, ResponseShow.class);
```

This is my `ResponseShow` class:

```
public class ResponseShow {

    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;    
    @SerializedName("lang")
    public String lang;    
    @SerializedName("guid")
    public String guid;    
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;    
    @SerializedName("tags")
    public String tags;    
    @SerializedName("address")
    public String address;    
    @SerializedName("description")
    public String description;    
    @SerializedName("size")
    public String size;    
    @SerializedName("url")
    public String url;    
    @SerializedName("email")
    public String email;    
    @SerializedName("fax")
    public String fax;    
    @SerializedName("tel")
    public String tel;    
    @SerializedName("total_votes")
    public String total_votes;    
    @SerializedName("total_values")
    public String total_values;    
    @SerializedName("rate")
    public String rate;    
    @SerializedName("open2424")
    public String open2424;    
    @SerializedName("category_main_name")
    public String category_main_name;    
    @SerializedName("category_name")
    public String category_name;    
    @SerializedName("category_main_name2")
    public String category_main_name2;    
    @SerializedName("category_name2")
    public String category_name2;    
    @SerializedName("category_main_name3")
    public String category_main_name3;    
    @SerializedName("category_name3")
    public String category_name3;    
    @SerializedName("park_type")
    public String park_type;    
    @SerializedName("park_handicap")
    public String park_handicap;    
    @SerializedName("park_free")
    public String park_free;    
    @SerializedName("park_description")
    public String park_description;    
    @SerializedName("datemodinfo")
    public String datemodinfo;    
    @SerializedName("sponsor")
    public String sponsor;    
    @SerializedName("sponsorstart")
    public String sponsorstart;    
    @SerializedName("sponsorend")
    public String sponsorend;    
    @SerializedName("town")
    public String town;    
    @SerializedName("area")
    public String area;    
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    public String latitude;    
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    public String longitude;    
    @SerializedName("distance_info")
    public Map<String, String> distance_info = new HashMap<String, String>();    
    @SerializedName("zip")
    public String zip;    
    @SerializedName("image")
    public String image;    
    @SerializedName("ligoo_url")
    public String ligoo_url;    
    @SerializedName("open")
    public int open;    
    public List<openinghours> openinghours;    
    @SerializedName("query")
    public String query;
}
```

This is my `openinghours` class:

```
public class openinghours {

    public List<schedules> schedules;       
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;

}
```

This is my `Schedules` class:

```
public class schedules {

    public List<day0> day0;
    public List<day1> day1;
    public List<day2> day2;
    public List<day3> day3;
    public List<day4> day4;
    public List<day5> day5;
    public List<day6> day6;
}
```

And my `day0` class:

```
public class day0 {

    @SerializedName("date")
    public String date;         
    public List<periods> periods; 
}
```

The problem is that I get the following error while trying to parse `day0`:

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY goal was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2414
```

Comment: Post your parsing related code also. The problem is involving those code

Comment: the json you provided has an error. It has a closing ']' but no open '['. 

This might be a copy paste error, but maybe you will add the first character to make it easier to detect the real problem

Comment: what is your day0 class..?? even you dont need to create different class for day0 and and other days as it has just change of label else all childrens are same.

Comment: I have changed the question...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the class `openinghours` (which btw should be in uppercase!). There, you're trying to parse the field `"schedules"` into a `List`, and as you can see in your JSON, it's not a `List`, but an object (it's surrounded by `{ }`).

Concretely, the `"schedules"` field looks like:

```
"schedules": {
    "day0": {
        ...
    },
    "day1": {
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

So, the fastest solution for you would be just to replace the type of the attribute `schedules` in your `openinghours` class by:

```
public schedules schedules;
```

Because the JSON field `"schedules"` is an **object** that contains several fields `day0`, `day1`, etc... And that's exactly what your class `schedules` is... So, this should work for you!

---

Anyway, the best solution is to use a `Map` this in your `openinghours` class:

```
public Map<String, Day> schedules;
```

This is the best option because this is exactly what the JSON field `"schedules"` represents... Moreover, this way you can have only one class `Day` instead of many classes `day0`, `day1`, etc... which makes much much more sense!

Comment: @Buchssullivan: just let me remind you that you can accept this answer if you consider it valid and useful... or you can always comment if you need more help on this...

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
public class openinghours {
    public List<schedules> schedules;       
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;
}
```

//by

```
public class openinghours {
    public  schedules  schedules;       
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;
}
```

You might define a class for your distance_info():

```
class DistanceInfo{
    private int distance;
    private unit;
}
```

//change

```
@SerializedName("distance_info")
public Map<String, String> distance_info = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

//to

```
@SerializedName("distance_info")
public DistanceInfo distance_info;
```